# Getting Java to recognize user input

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a virtual store program.  Synopsis is if at any time the user enters 'q', the program should quit.

Once the user enters 'c', ask the user to enter a 2-character state such as CA, NV, WA. If a code other

than these three is entered, it falls under "other". Then display what is in their cart and the calculated
total price based on discounts and include the tax.

The problem is that the program would ask user for item and quantity once, then it goes into checkout mode. Whenever I put 'q', it goes to the next line.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.*;


public class virtualStore {


    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{

        /* If the user enters an item number, the program should ask the user to enter how many of that item
        they want, and then print the menu again. If at any time the user enters 'q', the program should quit.
        Once the user enters 'c', ask the user to enter a 2-character state such as CA, NV, WA. If a code other
        than these three is entered, it falls under "other". Then display what is in their cart and the calculated
        total price based on discounts and include the tax. You should use the Math.round() and
        System.out.printf methods to round numbers and to display to 2 decimal places. */

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        String input;
        char c = ' ';
        char q = ' ';

        //tax rates
        double CAtaxRate = .09;
        double NVtaxRate = .07;
        double WAtaxRate = .065;
        double other = .06;
        double tax = 0; 

        //checkout
        double checkout = 0;
        double total;
        double cash = 0;
        double change = 0;
        //items
        double mushrooms = 0.3;
        double onions = 0.6;
        double watermelon = 2.5;
        double cookies = 1;
        int item = 0;

        //number of items
        int numMushrooms = 0;
        int numOnions = 0;
        int numWatermelon = 0;
        int numCookies = 0;



        DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to Alex's Store."
                + " Here is the menu. "
                + "\nEnter the item number to add it to your cart,"
                + " enter \'c\' to checkout or \'q\' to quit. ");

        while(true)
        //while(c != 'c' && c != 'q')

        {

            for (item = 1; item < 4; item ++){
            System.out.println("Item\t\t\tPrice\t\t\tQuantity");
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("1. Mushrooms\t\t($0.30/$0.25)\t\t" + numMushrooms);
            System.out.println("2. Onions\t\t($0.60/$0.50)\t\t" + numOnions );
            System.out.println("3. Watermelon\t\t($2.50/$2.00)\t\t" + numWatermelon);
            System.out.println("4. Cookies\t\t($1.00/$0.75)\t\t" + numCookies);
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------");


            System.out.println("Enter item number between 1 through 4");
            System.out.println("or enter 'c' for checkout or 'q' for quit.");
            input = keyboard.nextLine();
            item = Integer.parseInt(input);




            if (input.equals("1")) 
            {
                System.out.println("Enter how many items you want.");
                String m = keyboard.nextLine();
                numMushrooms = Integer.parseInt(m); 

            }
            else if (input.equals("2"))
            {
                System.out.println("Enter how many items you want.");
                String o = keyboard.nextLine();
                numOnions = Integer.parseInt(o);

            }
            else if (input.equals("3"))
            {
                System.out.println("Enter how many items you want.");
                String w = keyboard.nextLine();
                numWatermelon = Integer.parseInt(w);                

            }
            else if(input.equals("4"))
            {
                System.out.println("Enter how many items you want.");
                String co = keyboard.nextLine();
                numCookies = Integer.parseInt(co);

            }

            }





        if (numMushrooms  > 10)
        {
            mushrooms = 0.25;
        }

        else if (numOnions > 10)
        {
            onions = 0.5;
        }
        else if (numWatermelon > 10)
        {
            watermelon = 2;
        }
        else if (numCookies > 10)
        {
            cookies = .75;
        }

        // quit option
        String quit = scanner.nextLine();
        q = quit.charAt(0);

        if (quit.equalsIgnoreCase("q"))
        {   
            System.out.println("Goodbye");
            scanner.close();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        // checkout option
        String ch = scanner.nextLine();
        c = ch.charAt(0);

        if (ch.equalsIgnoreCase("c"))
        {


            //checkout
            checkout =  numMushrooms * mushrooms + numOnions * onions + numWatermelon * watermelon + numCookies * cookies;


            //tax
            total = tax * checkout + checkout;


            System.out.print("Enter state abbreviations: ");
            input = keyboard.nextLine();


            PrintWriter outputfile = new PrintWriter("receipt.txt");
            outputfile.println("Your cart: ");
            outputfile.println("Sub total:$ " + dollar.format(checkout));

            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("CA"))
            {
                total = CAtaxRate * checkout + checkout;
                outputfile.println("Tax Rate: " + CAtaxRate);
                outputfile.println("Tax: $" + dollar.format(CAtaxRate * checkout));
                outputfile.println("Total is: $" + dollar.format(total));
            }   

            else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("NV"))
            {
                total = NVtaxRate * checkout + checkout;
                outputfile.println("Tax Rate: " + NVtaxRate);
                outputfile.println("Tax: $" + dollar.format(NVtaxRate * checkout));
                outputfile.println("Total is: $" + dollar.format(total));

            }

            else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("WA"))
            {
                total = WAtaxRate * checkout + checkout;
                outputfile.println("Tax Rate: " + WAtaxRate);
                outputfile.println("Tax: $" + dollar.format(WAtaxRate * checkout));
                outputfile.println("Total is: $" + dollar.format(total));

            }

            else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase(input))
            {
                total = other * checkout + checkout;
                outputfile.println("Tax Rate: " + other);
                outputfile.println("Tax: $" + dollar.format(other * checkout));
                outputfile.println("Total is: $" + dollar.format(total));
            }

            outputfile.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
            input = keyboard.nextLine();
            cash = Integer.parseInt(input);
            outputfile.println("Enter amount of cash: $" + dollar.format(cash));

            change = cash - total;
            outputfile.println("Change due: $" + dollar.format(change));


            outputfile.println("Thank you for shopping at Alex's store!");

            outputfile.close();

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("receipt.text", true);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
        pw.println("C:\\Desktop\\Receipt.txt ");
        pw.close();
        } 







    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong model to get user input.

Try doing something that looks like:

```
while(true) {

    // Print the menu messages
    String input = scanner.readLine();
    if(input.equals("c")) {

        // Read in and handle state abbreviation

    } else if(input.equals("q")) {
        System.exit(0);
    } else {
        int itemNumber = Integer.parseInt(input);

        // Parse and handle item number
    }
}
```

Comment: Under "enter item number" section, the program doesn't ask for quantity.

Comment: You'll need to put that code where the code says `// Parse and handle line number`.

Comment: Under enter item, it doesn't store the user input. Also the input did not update the menu.

Comment: How should the input update the menu? You didn't specify that in your question.

Comment: Also, if you're using a loop, I'm pretty sure you want to increment the number of items with `+=`, not overwrite it.

Comment: After I input a number on how many items I want and push enter, it was supposed to change the 'quantity' number on the menu. It was supposed to look like: 

Enter item number between 1 through 4
or enter 'c' for checkout or 'q' for quit.
1
Enter how many items you want.
5
Item   Price   Quantity
---------------------------------------------------------
1. Mushrooms  ($0.30/$0.25)  5
2. Onions  ($0.60/$0.50)  0
3. Watermelon  ($2.50/$2.00)  0
4. Cookies  ($1.00/$0.75)  0
---------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Do you have the code that prints out the menu inside the while loop? Are you sure you're not declaring the "number of" variables inside the loop? Are you sure you're incrementing the variables properly? (Just some off-the-top-of-my-head debugging tips)

Comment: Yea. The variables are declared outside the loop. I keep getting error messages like : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "c"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at virtualStore.main(virtualStore.java:79)

when ever i try to push 'c' or 'q' when it's asking me to 'enter item numbers 1 through 4'.